# Base64 Decode Text File To Bin File In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, base64, decode

I have a text file and I want to decode it to binary code file.

Currently, I'm using `openssl` on Windows to do this. 
The command is: `base64 -d input.txt output.bin`

What could be the equivalent Python's `base64` command for this?

Edit:

`input.txt` Content:

```
India
USA
Africa
Europe
```

My try:

```
InputFile = open('input.txt', 'r')
InputFile_Content = InputFile.read()
print(InputFile_Content)

print(base64.decode(InputFile_Content, 'Output.bin'))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(base64.decode(InputFile_Content, 'Output.bin'))
  File "Python\Python37\lib\base64.py", line 502, in decode
    line = input.readline()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readline'
```

Comment: then you should do some research before asking the question

Comment: post the code you have tried and error also

Comment: You can use the [base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) module or [binascii](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html).

Comment: Added @komatiraju032 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search brought up [this](https://stackabuse.com/encoding-and-decoding-base64-strings-in-python/) article about encoding and decoding base64 strings. Probably a good way to do that in python is to do:

```py
import base64

with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    message = f.read().encode("ascii")

with open("output.bin", "wb") as f:
    f.write(base64.b64encode(message))
```

Comment: After seeing your edit, I think my answer is still what you are looking for. I would look into how to properly open and edit files using `with open` in Python.

Comment: If my answer helps, please do mark it as the correct answer!

Comment: Sure, I'll do that. I'm testing it on my code. Once I get expected output, I'll mark your answer.